# Return variables from a function with a while loop

Tags: python, list, while-loop, return, assign

I am new to Python, thus apologize in advance! I am trying to return two lists from a function with a while loop that reads an xml file. I can't figure out how to do it. I am referring to imres (integer) and subres (2 integers) in the code below, that are found ~10 times in the loop. Debuging shows that the variables are properly filled in the loop, but I don't know how to return the filled lists and I get the empty lists instead. Thanks.

```
def getresolution(node):
    imres = []
    subres = []
    child4 = node.firstChild
    while child4:
                ...
        for child8 in keepElementNodes(child7.childNodes):
            if child8.getAttribute('Hash:key') == 'ImageSize':
                X = float(child8.getElementsByTagName('Size:width')[0].firstChild.data)
                Y = float(child8.getElementsByTagName('Size:height')[0].firstChild.data)
                imres += [[X, Y]]
            if child8.getAttribute('Hash:key') == 'Resolution':
                subres += [int(child8.firstChild.data)]
        getresolution(child4)
        child4 = child4.nextSibling
    return [imres, subres]


[imres, subres] = getresolution(xml_file)
```

Comment: It's hard to say without a full [mcve], but I'm suspicious of that `getresolution(child4)` call. If you're expecting the recursive call to append its results to the top-level imres and subres objects, that's not going to happen automatically. You need to assign the result of `getresolution(child4)` to something and incorporate that data into your lists manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested but this should point you in the right direction:

```py
def getresolution(node):
    imres = []
    subres = []
    child4 = node.firstChild
    while child4:
                ...
        for child8 in keepElementNodes(child7.childNodes):
            if child8.getAttribute('Hash:key') == 'ImageSize':
                X = float(child8.getElementsByTagName('Size:width')[0].firstChild.data)
                Y = float(child8.getElementsByTagName('Size:height')[0].firstChild.data)
                imres += [[X, Y]]
                if child8.getAttribute('Hash:key') == 'Resolution':
                    subres += [int(child8.firstChild.data)]
        t_imres, t_subres = getresolution(child4)
        imres += t_imres
        subres += t_subres
        child4 = child4.nextSibling
    return [imres, subres]


[imres, subres] = getresolution(xml_file)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is giving me an error:                                                                                 imres, subres += getresolution(child4)
    ^ 
SyntaxError: illegal expression for augmented assignment

Comment: I have modified it

Comment: That worked tvgiek. The solution makes little sense to me at the moment, since it looks like there are two lines that fill each list. But I'll get used to it. Thanks again!